# sendRedirect is not working for jsp but working for html page

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

```
> System.out.println("Coming here for Voting");
>       //response.sendRedirect("NewFile.html");-----> This is working
>       response.sendRedirect("Survey.jsp");-------> THis is not working getting 404 error.
```

Both HTML and JSP in same default folder..ie [image]

I tried with response.sendRedirect("./Survey.jsp") also not working getting 404

Comment: Pardon me if it was intentional, but the file you have listed there is named `Servey.jsp`, not `Survey.jsp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your jsp file in the program is spelled Servey while your code is spelled Survey

Comment: Thanks man...wow I'm looking all other things...you saved my day..thxs